# DOCTYPE in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, html5

How to change the Document Mode in Internet Explorer to Standards value by using visual force page coding ?
I need it to display the page correctly in IE.

Comment: Based on some the answers below, can you be more specific as to what the page needs?  As Avidev notes, you can set the docType attribute to specify the actual HTML doctype.  As jkraybill and Mohith point out - you can set a meta tag which will have some browsers (like IE) behave like a specific version.

Comment: This question needs to be separate into 2(separate questions), So a DOCTYPE question needs to be separated.

Answer (score 42):

There is a docType attribute in `<apex:page>` component you can set that to **html-5.0**

**For Example**

```
 <apex:page docType="html-5.0" />
```

Comment: I want to change the Document Mode to "Standards" Value in Internet explorer using coding which is not accomplished by above code if you have any work around please suggest me.

Comment: This does answer the question as it's phrased, but the solution is as per Jeremy's answer. It might be prudent to update the question to demonstrate why it renders incorrectly in IE.

Answer (score 4):

I think you'll find the answer on this question helpful, it involves setting the X-UA-Compatible header via Apex. [IE10 Forced into IE7 Standards document mode for Visualforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8298/ie10-forced-into-ie7-standards-document-mode-for-visualforce/8301#8301)

Answer (score 1):

http://css.dzone.com/articles/document-compatibility-modes

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950598/ie8-browser-mode-vs-document-mode

One alternative is always adding the metatag

```
<head>
<title>The Page Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
</head>
```

Comment: No Mohit above code doesn't change the document mode of IE to standards value.

Comment: Document Mode is overridden by the compatibility mode in IE.The compatibility mode along with doctype set determines the document mode.You may like to read the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950598/ie8-browser-mode-vs-document-mode.                                             my answer explains how to change compactibility mode and Aridev one gives how to set doctype.Using combination of those you must reach to answer

Answer (score 0):

To enable standards mode, you can include the html `DOCTYPE` declaration in a Visualforce page using an unescaped `apex:outputText` element at the beginning of the page, but it only works up until API version 26.0.

```
<apex:page contentType="text/html" docType="html" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false">
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="<!DOCTYPE html>"/>
    <body onload="document.write((document.compatMode === 'CSS1Compat' ? 'Standards' : 'Quirks') + ' Mode');">
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

Set the apiVersion in your metadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexPage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <!-- Version CANNOT be greater than 26.0 to set doctype -->
        <apiVersion>26.0</apiVersion>
        <label>Doctype Example</label>
</ApexPage>
```